# What would be the monthly hosting cost for eSchool Smart System

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, linux, servers

I have no idea about DevOps. Sorry in advance if the question is something not relevant.

> I have to propose a cost of yearly/monthly for a system. The system will have two versions. Web (React & Laravel separate projects) & App (Android). Initially the eSchool Smart System beta version will be launched 10000 Schools where there will features such as for different kind kf users Admin, Student, Teacher, Parents. Besides there will be real-time messaging feature.

Based on this brief what will be the approx cost per month/year to host the system?

Last but not the least, can anyone share the details configuration such as server, space, etc things.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much storage your school needs for storing files and concurrent requests that come from your web and mobile application users.

You can use [infracost](https://github.com/infracost/infracost) to estimate cost on different cloud services.